# Prevent SQL query from hogging database resources. Set max usage?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a .NET application using ADO.NET and Entity Framework and a lot of legacy stored procedures. Occasionally an operation will bring the database server's CPU to 100% for seconds or even minutes. During this time no other operations can be executed against the database. There is some culprit code which is far too complex and business critical to be feasible refactoring in the short term, but this can also happen from newer code depending on the situation.

I would like to prevent any one SQL operation from taking 100% of the CPU, etc. Is there any way to configure MS SQL to provide no more than, say 20% of the CPU, to any one query?

I know that ideally we would rewrite the code to not be as intensive, but that is not feasible in the short term, so I'm looking for a general setting which ensure this can never happen.

Comment: Don't you expect that doing so would make your situation worse? If you bring down the cpu allowance to 80% the cpu hogging will take longer...

Comment: And this more of a db issue than a programming issue but I'm not sure if tuning as broadly stated as this is on-topic on dba.se

Comment: You can't tell sql server to only allow up to 20% cpu for a single query. Logically this just doesn't work anyway because you are trying to prevent 100% cpu utilization. What happens when you have 6 queries each needing 20%? You can throttle cpu usage overall and limit it to a percentage of cpu. This is done with the resource governor. But you can't be as granular as each query. If you have cpu utilization at 100% for several minutes you are in critical need of performance tuning.

Comment: i'd recommend checking to ensure the instance is configured correctly as well. take a look [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/the-accidental-dba-day-4-of-30-sql-server-installation-and-configuration-best-practices/) which will lead to other links on ensuring proper configuration. otherwise - you're going to need to refactor. the productivity gains that an ORM provides are lost at runtime.

Comment: This question is far too broad..

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Resource Governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) (assuming you're using SQL 2008 or up). A good simple overview on usage [is here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/04/sql-server-simple-example-to-configure-resource-governor-introduction-to-resource-governor/).  Though it won't work necessarily on a specific query, using a reasonable classifier function will/should allow you to narrow it down pretty closely if you like.  I don't have 10 rep yet so I can only post 2 links, but if you google "Sql Server classifier function" you'll get some decent guidance.